# How to search using the value returned by function

Tags: vim, editor

I would like to search using current filename in this file. I already know getting current filename using `:call expand("%:p:h")`. So i'd like to using some command like `/call expand("%:p:h")` to search. I tried this but failed, because vim parse this function call literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to insert in command-line (or just in insert mode) a value, returned by some function, you should use the following:

<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>function_name()<kbd>Enter</kbd>

By the way, you said that `expand("%:p:h")` returns current filename, but this is wrong: actually it returns full path to current file, without filename. To get just a filename without a path, you should use `expand("%:t")`. Please read `:help expand` to get more info.

**EDITED:** In your case, you can use solution with *search register* `@/` that @ib suggested: this is a safer way. But if i need just to find filename in the buffer, and if my filename does not contain some special characters, I would use <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> instead.

So, the whole expression to search current filename, is:

`/\V`<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>`expand('%:t')`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

P.S.

`\V` at the beginning of the search pattern means "*very nomagic*" mode. You can read about it here:  `:help \V`

Comment: While using the expression register when entering search pattern is a convenient option, result is *not* the same.  Since you insert the path name interactively, even if you escape backslash sequences with `escape(expand('%'),'\')` (other pitfalls are canceled out by the "very nomagic" mode, that is right), you have to escape the character that is used to start the search (`/` or `?`).  And here is the catch: One cannot protect occurrences of both of those symbols regardless of search direction!  (Escaping of `?` in a forward search transforms a question mark into the `\?` atom.)

Comment: i used `expand("%:t")` in my expression, and i explained, why i did so. This is already enough to say that result is not the same. And in this case there's almost never need to escape something with `\V`.  Well, but the following expression is absolutelly the same as you suggested: `/\V<Ctrl+R>=escape(expand('%:p:h'), '\')<Enter><Enter>`   and, well, i don't really understand why do you suggest to escape `'\'` characters, because Vim always use `'/'` path delimeter (both on my Windows and Linux machines). If i need to escape, i would escape `'/?'` chars.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the search expression from your last comment does *not* have the same effect in every case.  It is easy to see: Open the `/tmp/test` file, for example.  The search command you propose would search for empty pattern (in contrast to that command from my answer)!

Comment: Not to mention that it is absolutely legal for a file (or directory) name to contain backslashes (at least, on Unix-like systems).

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. You are right: result is not the same. Sorry.

Comment: To sum up for future readers:  Note that this approach stil works only for limited set of cases.  Even presence of `/` or `\ ` can easily brake it!

Comment: Really thanks. I search for this answer for several weeks. And even asked twice here. ctrl+R = is so cool.

Answer (score 1):

If the current file name does not contain symbols that should be escaped due
to Vim pattern syntax (see `:help pattern`), then one can just type

> `/`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>`%`

Otherwise, one have to prepare the current file name, put it into the last
search register,

```
:let @/ = '\V' . escape(expand('%:p:h'), '\')
```

and issue a search command manually using `n`/`N`, `/`<kbd>Enter</kbd> or
`?`<kbd>Enter</kbd>.  To reduce typing, mappings combining these steps can be
introduced.

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>f/ ExpandSearch('/')
nnoremap <expr> <leader>f? ExpandSearch('?')
function! ExpandSearch(dir)
    let @/ = '\V' . escape(expand('%:p:h'), '\')
    return a:dir . "\r"
endfunction
```

There is also a similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd> but more
general command line expansion feature, the expression register.  One can type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> while editing search pattern, enter
an expression (see `:help expression`), and result of its evaluation would be
inserted right into the location where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> keystroke
was pressed.  Unfortunately, besides the usual escaping issues resolved above
with the `\V` atom and an `escape()` call, this way of expansion creates a new
one.  Since the path name is inserted interactively, one also have to escape
the character that is used to run the search command (`/` or `?`).  Sadly, it
is not possible to protect occurrences of both of those symbols regardless of
search direction: Escaping of `?` in a forward search transforms a question
mark into the `\?` atom mangling the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function in vim called `search()` which will move your cursor to your pattern:

```
:call search(expand("%:p:h"))
```

There's another function called `matchadd()` which will highlight your pattern:

```
:call matchadd('Search', expand("%:p:h"))
```

If filename contains special chars, such as `.*[]`, you should call `escape()`:

```
:call search(escape(expand("%:p:h"), '.*[]'))
```

---

```
search({pattern} [, {flags} [, {stopline} [, {timeout}]]])  *search()*
        Search for regexp pattern {pattern}.  The search starts at the
        cursor position (you can use |cursor()| to set it).

matchadd({group}, {pattern}[, {priority}[, {id}]])
        Defines a pattern to be highlighted in the current window (a
        "match").  It will be highlighted with {group}.  Returns an
        identification number (ID), which can be used to delete the
        match using |matchdelete()|.

escape({string}, {chars})               *escape()*
        Escape the characters in {chars} that occur in {string} with a
        backslash.  Example:  
            :echo escape('c:\program files\vim', ' \')
        results in:  
            c:\\program\ files\\vim
        Also see |shellescape()|.
```

Comment: Beware of using this command: If the current file name happens to contain a "special" character interfering with Vim search pattern syntax, the command does not work properly!

Comment: Calling the `search()` function is inferior to using search commands. For example, a search pattern is not remembered in the last search register, thus making jumping to the next/previous occurrence of the pattern impossible using default `n`/`N` commands.  The same applies to adding custom highlighting patterns using the `:match` command or the `matchadd()` function.

Comment: Note that a file name is not correctly escaped in the last command! For example, if that file name contains backslashes, it can significantly mangle the pattern.